# How to post data in php using curl and headers

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to use a payment gateway api using php and they said api request will post data using curl, my app is using php code and I don't know how to do that in php file... they provide a sample code, but when I tried to copy and paste the code in php file it shows syntax error.  Please help me to do that in php.  Link for the payment api that i am using is https://paycertify.com/docs/api/gateway/recurring-billing/create-a-subscription/

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://gateway-api.paycertify.com/api/subscriptions \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_TOKEN' \
  --form 'amount=1.00' \
  --form 'description=Monthly tennis club signature' \
  --form 'start_date=2018-09-07' \
  --form 'end_date=2018-10-07' \
  --form 'interval=day' \
  --form 'card_number=4111111111111111' \
  --form 'merchant_subscription_id=MY-ORDER' \
  --form 'interval_count=1' \
  --form 'card_expiry_month=01' \
  --form 'card_expiry_year=2021' \
  --form 'card_cvv=999' \
  --form 'first_name=John' \
  --form 'last_name=Doe' \
  --form 'street_address_1=59 N Santa Cruz Avenue' \
  --form 'street_address_2=Suite M' \
  --form 'city=Los Gatos' \
  --form 'state=CA' \
  --form 'country=US' \
  --form 'mobile_phone=+11231231234' \
  --form 'email=support@paycertify.com' \
  --form 'merchant_transaction_id=my-order-id-0001' \
  --form 'zip=95030'
```

Answer (score 0):

This exemple is a shell command. If you want to send data to the api, you will need to use the curl php method.
Try something like this

```
$curlHandler = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curlHandler, [
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://gateway-api.paycertify.com/api/subscriptions',//url you want to call
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,//receive server reponse
    CURLOPT_POST => true,//Explain you are using the post method
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: Bearer YOUR_API_TOKEN"),

    /**
     * An array of field you want to send
     */
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => [
        'amount' => '1.00',
        'description' => 'Monthly tennis club signature',
        ....
    ],
]);

$response = curl_exec($curlHandler);

curl_close($curlHandler);

echo($response);
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for your reply... i have tried the code that you have sent but it is showing error unexpected " ; " in CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER and when i put the "," instead of " ; " then it shows the runtime error "curl_setopt_array(): You must pass either an object or an array with the CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER argument in C:\Program Files (x86)\Ampps\www\paycertify\payment.php on line 29"

Comment: @UsmanLiaqat Did you change "YOUR_API_TOKEN" by your token ? I've edit my code too, can you try again ?